# How to convert foreach into for loop in php

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I would like to convert this to for loop. How would I implement it? Please help. Thank you!

```
foreach ($friends as $friend){
  foreach ($friend as $myFriends){

    $id = $myFriends['id'];
    $name = $myFriends['name'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: `for($i=0; $i<count($friends); $i++)` ... but why???

Comment: Coz I'm using nested foreach and i want to change the first one into for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you would want to do this? My only guess is that you would like the index but that can be achieved using the following syntax:

```
foreach($friends as $index => $friend)
```

This will allow you to continue using a convenient and clean foreach while accessing the index if need be.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($friends);$i++){
    $friend = $friends[$i];
      for($j=0; $j<count($friend); $j++){
        $myFriends= $friend[$j];
        $id = $myFriends['id'];
        $name = $myFriends['name'];
      }
   }
```

Maybe this code spent much resource while compared to foreach.

Comment: what do you mean? Is it about time consuming?